# Deleting Entries In A Junction Table In Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

This is a question about Entity Framework (EF) version 6.

I have three tables. TableA, TableB and TableJ like so:

```
TableA
int Id (primary key)

TableB
int Id (primary key)

TableJ
int TableAId (primary key)
int TableBId (primary key)
```

Table J is a junction/mapping/many-to-many table between Table A and Table B. Note that there are no foreign keys. Mapping these tables in EF, I have the following code:

```
public partial class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public partial class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to delete the entries in the junction/mapping/many-to-many table. For example, this code doesn't delete anything:

```
var a = db.As.Find(id);
a.Bs.Clear();
db.SaveChanges();
```

What do I need to do to delete the entries in the junction/mapping/many-to-many table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clear()` doesn't actually have any effect on the object from the perspective of the context, it just clears the in-memory collection of any existing elements; instead you would do something like this:

```
var a = db.As.Find(id);
var removals = a.Bs.ToList(); //or you could filter to only remove B objects matching a specific criteria, etc.
foreach (var remove in removals)
{
   a.Bs.Remove(remove);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

This materialises all of `Bs` in `a` and then removes each one from the `a.Bs` collection - then when you `SaveChanges` the objects will be deleted from the database.

Incidentally, the reason we materialise first is because we can't both enumerate *and* remove from `a.Bs` at the same time, or we will get the old "Collection modified during enumeration" error